# How to find the size of an element in the document

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The offsetHeight of the custom polymer element main-app is 88px in main(). 
When the same offsetHeight method is called in a click handler, it's 108px.
I'm guessing it's a timing issue.
 
Is there any event of method, that let me run a call-back when a custom polymer element is completely ready in the document?

```
main() async {
  await initPolymer();

  PaperButton pb = querySelector('paper-button');
  MainApp sa = querySelector('main-app');
  if(sa != null){
    print('main-app');
    print(sa.style.width.runtimeType);
    print('offset:' + sa.offset.toString());
    print('offsetHeight:' + sa.offsetHeight.toString());
    print('offsetWidth:' + sa.offsetWidth.toString());
    print('getBoundingClientRect:'+sa.getBoundingClientRect().toString());
    print('contentedge:'+sa.contentEdge.toString());
    print('clientHeight:'+sa.clientHeight.toString());
    print('client:'+sa.client.toString());
    print('marginEdge:'+sa.marginEdge.toString());
  }
  pb.on['tap'].listen((_) {
    print('Button tapped!');
    print('offsetHeight:' + sa.offsetHeight.toString());
  });
}
```

Output:

```
main-app
String
offset:Rectangle (8, 8) 643 x 88
offsetHeight:88
offsetWidth:643
getBoundingClientRect:Rectangle (8.0, 8.0) 642.6666870117188 x 88.0
contentedge:Rectangle (8.0, 8.0) 643 x 88
clientHeight:88
client:Rectangle (0, 0) 643 x 88
marginEdge:Rectangle (8.0, 8.0) 643 x 88
index.html:6095 Button tapped!
index.html:6095 offsetHeight:108
```

**Edit:**
Günter Zöchbauer's new Future((){}) works, although it's hacky.
Another unfortunate discovery from this is that the initialization of child node occurs before the parent node size is set.
In my component:

```
attached() {
    super.attached();
    print('main-app parent offset in attached:'+parent.offset.toString());
  }
```

In main:

```
print('main-app');
pb.on['tap'].listen((_) {
    print('Button tapped!');
    print('main-app parent offset:'+ sa.parent.offset.toString());
  });
```

Output(respectively):

```
main-app parent offset in attached:Rectangle (0, 0) 643 x 246
main-app
Button tapped!
main-app parent offset:Rectangle (0, 0) 643 x 334
```

Fortunately the execution of main seems to be in the queue at the point attached() is invoked, so creating a component that resizes itself based on the parent node size is possible using Future().
 
Hope Future() stays reliable.

## Another answer

I have finally found it!!
https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/local-dom

> Async operations: The insert, append, and remove operations are
>   transacted lazily in certain cases for performance. In order to
>   interrogate the DOM (e.g. offsetHeight, getComputedStyle, etc.)
>   immediately after one of these operations, call PolymerDom.flush()
>   first.

PolymerDom.flush() is what I needed. 
But as I mentioned in the comment, Future should still be used.

Comment: You can answer your own question and also make it the accepted answer (after some delay).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that and thanks a lot for your answer too.

Comment: The thing is, while "PolymerDom.flush()" is a more suitable answer to my question alone, it's not always enough because components are initialized before main() gets executed(Well, you sure know that). So calling flush a real answer was probably wrong, because it's only half the answer:elements added later might change the size of the component etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard events for this. Usually it works by just scheduling your code for the next event loop to allow Polymer to complete its work by wrapping your code in

```
new Future((){
  // your code here 
} );`
```

If it's your own component you could fire an event yourself in `attached()` but to be sure the code that fires the event should alse be wrapped in a future (template if/for for example might not be completed in `attached()`)